# C++ expression must have a constant value. (i was writing a code in C in Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c, visual-studio

I tried to initialize a 2D array in C using integers inputted by the user but Visual Studio 2019 is showing me this error? The code worked fine on Codelite using a gcc compiler. 
List of errors

```
 error C2057: expected constant expression
 error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
 error C2057: expected constant expression
 error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
 error C2087: 'board': missing subscript
 error C2133: 'board': unknown size
```

Comment: Showing your code and errors would be really, really helpful even though it appears that @dbush might have been able to read your mind.

Comment: @player_pi it is usually more clear to include code examples when asking questions :-)  then it's easier to figure out exactly what you mean in more details

Comment: Please edit your post to include a text version of the code, plus a text version of the errors. SO frowns upon images and external resources - the pic of errors you're getting don't help us see the code.

Comment: If you're going to remove the picture, you need to replace it with text.  Otherwise the question doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Hi! I made the changes and added text instead of the pic

Answer (score 1):

MSVC has minimal support for the C99 standard.  A consequence of this is that it does not support variable length arrays (VLA).

You'll need to allocate space dynamically.

```
int n=5,m=5;
int i;
int **arr;

arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I have to dynamically allocate the array or use CMAKE with a compiler like gcc or clang to get support for vla on Visual Studio 2019